# Change User Folder

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, windows-backup

So I had a backup and when restored it to my computer the User folder didn't actually change to use the backed-up folder, so now I have an `owner` folder (which is pretty much empty) and a `my_username` folder below `C:\Users`. How can I make my account use the `my_username` folder as the user folder?

EDIT:
I've tried creating a new account and then changing the name of my old folder to the name of the new account, but somehow Windows still knows it's not the 'real' user folder and creates a TEMP folder. In which registry is this configured?

Answer (score 2):

Open **regedit** and navigate to:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList
```

Click one of the profiles under ProfileList hierarchy, and look at the right side - there's **ProfileImagePath** key.

Find the profile that uses your current folder and change the **ProfileImagePath** value to the one you need to use.

Reboot or re-login

Here's [more detailed description](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/87555-user-profile-change-default-location.html). Look at the 11-th step.

Comment: ProfileImagePath is the key.

Comment: When restarted it created a new /Users/TEMP folder and is using it as the user folder. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: You need to change owner and permissions of that old profile folder.

Comment: Did that and when re-logged, Windows just replaced that folder with an empty User folder. Thankfuly I still have everything backed. Any more ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Does your user account belong to local administrators group? When I was doing that in the past with 30+ computers (Windows XP/Vista/7) all of the users were in local administrators group... Try that...